# How do you get rid of this "email action bar" from Outlook?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

I have three Windows environments in which I run Outlook. In only one I end up with this thing I've arbitrarily called the "email action bar". I don't know what is it actually called. I'd upload a picture, but I don't have sufficient reputation. So, let me describe it as best I can.

It is a set of seven icons to the left of the reading pane. The first is the delete "x", the second is the move icon, the third is the flag icon.  I want these to appear on the email when I hover, not to the right of the reading pane. I don't have it in any of my other setups. What is going on?

How do I get rid of this?

Answer (score 3):

You need to go into "mouse mode" rather than "touch mode". You may [see the option](http://www.slipstick.com/outlook/2013/outlook-2013-touch-screen-mode/) to toggle between these modes in your Quick Access Toolbar. If it is not there, you can add it from the drop-down list at the end of the tool bar. Once you are in mouse mode, the "email action bar" will disappear.